# NServiceBus - How can I use my favorite container in a NServiceBus Endpoint?

Tags: nservicebus

I have 3 projects, one project is ASP.NET MVC and the other are dll library. In my ASP.NET project, I can use my NServiceBus.Unity container, for instance:

```
IStartableBus startableBus = Configure.With()
                .UnityBuilder(MyUnityContainer)
                .UseTransport<Msmq>()
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                .UnicastBus()
                .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
                .CreateBus();
```

But I can't initialize my NServiceBus.Unity container in the other endpoint dll library.

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, INeedInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With().UnityBuilder(MyUnityContainer);
    }
}
```

In this point, when I set a breakpoint and when I check the Configure.Instance, I can see that the default Autofac already is instantiate and it has a lot of type already registered. How can I use my favorite container in an Endpoint?

NServiceBus Version: 4.6.5

regards,
Juan Antonio Vázquez

Answer (score 0):

Use IWantCustomInitialization instead of INeedInitialization